# How can I obtain XML empty tag when I obtain null value from a DSS service into an ESB application generating an XML document?

Tags: wso2, integration, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I am absolutly new in **WSO2** project and I have the following problem. I am working on an Enterprise Intergrator project (that involves **ESB** and **DSS** components).

I am generating an XML document starting from data contained into some database tables. These data are aggregate using a pretty complex logic.

My problem is the following one:

into my **ESB flow** I have these chained **enrich** mediator used a create this section of the final XML document, this is the code:

```
<!-- add placeholders for additional <sampleid> and <provenance> tags -->
<enrich>
    <source clone="true" type="inline">
        <parent xmlns="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
            <sampleid>[pgrfas.prov_sid]</sampleid>
            <provenance>[pgrfas.provenance]</provenance>
        </parent>
    </source>
    <target property="moreValues" type="property"/>
</enrich>
<!--  Copy values for <sampleid> and <provenance> tags  -->
<enrich>
    <source clone="true" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xpath="$ctx:moreValues/child::*"/>
    <target action="child" xmlns:ds="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xpath="$ctx:serviceCall//ds:register/ds:acquisition"/>
</enrich>
<enrich>
    <source clone="true" xmlns:ds="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xpath="$ctx:sampleData//ds:Sample/ds:prov_sid/text()"/>
    <target action="child" xmlns:ds="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xpath="$ctx:serviceCall//ds:register/ds:acquisition/ds:sampleid/text()"/>
</enrich>
```

As you can see in the first  mediator definition I am defining 2 **XML** element ( and ) by:

```
<parent xmlns="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
    <sampleid>[pgrfas.prov_sid]</sampleid>
    <provenance>[pgrfas.provenance]</provenance>
</parent>
```

Ad I am define 2 **placeholder** that should be replace with the data obtained from the DB by this chained following  mediators:

```
<enrich>
    <source clone="true" xmlns:ds="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xpath="$ctx:sampleData//ds:Sample/ds:prov_sid/text()"/>
    <target action="child" xmlns:ds="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xpath="$ctx:serviceCall//ds:register/ds:acquisition/ds:sampleid/text()"/>
</enrich>

<enrich>
    <source clone="true" xmlns:ds="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xpath="$ctx:sampleData//ds:Sample/ds:provenance"/>
    <target xmlns:ds="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xpath="$ctx:serviceCall//ds:register/ds:acquisition/ds:provenance"/>
</enrich>
```

This is the related section in the final XML document generated by this **EXB** application:

```
<sampleid>coll_sid-001</sampleid>
<missid>coll_miss_id-001</missid>
```

Where **coll_sid-001** and **coll_miss_id-001** are retrieved from the database by the **DSS** service (previously putted into the **$ctx:sampleData** property).

If into the database table on which the **DSS** query is perfromed there are the value related to the XML  and  field it works fine and I obtain the previous output.

If this table contains **null** value for these fields I obtain this output into the generated XML:

```
<sampleid>[pgrfas.coll_sid]</sampleid>
<missid>[pgrfas.coll_miss_id]</missid>
```

As you can see, if it can't find the related value on the DB table it put the defined placeholder into the generated XML.

This is not good for my purpose. If into the DB table are present **null** values I want obtain an empty tag into my generated XML document, something like this:

```
<sampleid />
<missid />
```

How can I fix this issue? Exist some simple workaround to obtain empty tag in this situation?

Comment: You say you generate the xml from some db tables. Can you share some code where we can see how you do that?

Comment: @frifle code of what? This is a WSO2 ESB application so the code to build the final XML document is the posted XML configuration that is a specific section of my execution flow. What do you exactly mean?

Answer (score 0):

Try it create your enrich in this way

```
<enrich>
    <source clone="true" type="inline">
        <parent xmlns="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
            <sampleid/>
            <provenance/>
        </parent>
    </source>
    <target property="moreValues" type="property"/>
</enrich>
```